# Why is Response.StatusCode set to 200 when Application_Error() is invoked?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, global-asax

In my MVC application I sometimes have unhandled exceptions and `Application_Error()` handler invoked.

The problem is if I access `Response.StatusCode` inside `Application_Error()` it happens to be `200` although there was an unhandled exception. I'd rather expect 500.

Why is it 200 although there was an unhandled exception?

Comment: This value is probably not the value the client receives. Probably was not updated yet. The ASP.NET pipeline is sometimes a mystery.

Comment: May this can help http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/57/getting-the-correct-http-status-codes-out-of-asp.net-custom-error-pages

Comment: I tried even changing it by doing Response.StatusCode=XXX. Still that doesn't reset it. WEIRD

Answer (score 1):

inside Application_Error() you may do this:

```
        var lastError = Server.GetLastError();

        var statusCode = 500;
        var httpException = lastError as HttpException;
        if (httpException != null)
            statusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
```

Comment: Great, except it doesn't explain why `Response.StatusCode` is 200.